# How do you create a fullscreen layout

Tags: css

I'm currently making a NextJS app which should have a fullscreen layout that does not change regardless of zoom level. At default zoom level, you see the header, footer, toolbar, and vertically-scrollable content window

[image]

When you zoom out, the size of the header, footer, toolbar, and content window remain fixed even if the content inside them changes size

[image]

Note that there are multiple types of toolbars and content windows that may be shown depending on what the user selects. I've been able to get a header and footer working by editing `_app.js`, but the toolbar and content window are not taking up the full remaining space if I zoom out because there is some extra `div` that is injected by NextJS at some point. I'm using inline styling with material UI.

Has anyone run into this issue before?

Comment: This has nothing to do with Next.js at all but purely a CSS one.

Comment: @Terry it is a nextjs question because next injects a top-level <div>, so you cannot do this through _app.js or _document.js AFAIK! I could be mistaken though ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one approach you could use for your layout, using CSS Grid. I'm defining the grid to have 12 columns, but you could set it up in any way you'd like.

Note, the following block means, *start from the 3rd grid line and span to the end of the grid*. This will satisfy your horizontal space requirements.

```css
main .main-content {
  grid-column: 3 / -1;
}
```

For the center column taking up the maximum space of the viewport, I'm using the following:

```css
grid-template-rows: auto 1fr auto;
```

The first `auto` is the header, the `1fr` is the middle section (most room), and the last `auto` is the footer.

Here's a demo.

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: auto 1fr auto;
  min-height: 100vh;
  min-height: 100dvh;
  gap: 0.5rem;
  padding: 0.5rem;
}

main {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr);  
  gap: 0.5rem;
}

main aside {
  grid-column: 1 / 3;
}

main .main-content {
  grid-column: 3 / -1;
}

header, main aside, .main-content, footer {
  background-color: #eee;
}

header,
footer,
main :where(aside, .main-content) { padding: 0.5rem;}
html, body { padding: 0; margin: 0; }

*, *::before, *::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <header>header</header>
  <main>  
    <aside>aside</aside>
    <div class="main-content">main content</div>
  </main>
  <footer>footer</footer>
</div>
```